# How to fit a normal curve into this R code?

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I'm trying to plot a simple curve over this really tiny data set in R, but the line won't show up on the graph (see photo). Wondering what specifically is wrong with this code:

```
Decline_Category <- c(1,2,3)
Number_of_Trees <- c(80,15,5)
plot(Decline_Category,Number_of_Trees,pch=19)

fit  <- lm(Number_of_Trees~Decline_Category)
xx <- seq(1,80, length=3)
plot(Decline_Category,Number_of_Trees,pch=19,ylim=c(0,100))
lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(=xx)), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: use `data.frame(Decline_Category=xx)` in your predict call

Comment: reading the error output of the code : Error: unexpected '=' in "lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(=" so you are missing Decline_Category in that line as mentioned by user20650 `lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(Decline_Category=xx)), col="red")`, then you get that diagonal line..

Comment: In other words, the data passed to predict must match, in structure, that of which you used to estimate the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your lines() function:
It should be

```
lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(Decline_Category=xx)), col="red")
```